# What happens when someone sends a Microsoft error report?

Tags: windows-error-reporting

sometimes, when software crashes on Windows (which, depending on the type of software and the Windows version, can be quite often), Windows offers to send a crash report (the infamous "X encountered an error and will be shut down" screen). What exactly happens when you send that, both on your computer and at Microsoft? Will Microsoft forward the report to the developers if it's not on their end? And why does this not happen on every crash?

Comment: Developers have to go through a process to get this infomration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[WER (Windows Error Reporting)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Error_Reporting) is a framework that Microsoft has set up to allow 3rd party developers (and Microsoft) improve the "user experience".  Every third party developer participating in the WER framework must define properties of the types of crashes it would like to collect from its users.  Among those is the number of crash dumps to collect.  Additionally, Microsoft will not automatically collect crash dumps until it has decided that the dump is not a one-time occurrence. Even then, the user has total control of the WER experience.  The user can decide what is collected and how often.

Answer (score 1):

After a software crashes, a crash dump file is sent to Microsoft which contains stack trace, list of threads etc information which can be used for debugging. These errors reports are submitted to a central database run by Microsoft which third-party developers can access. If issue is related with Microsoft products, Microsoft pushes the fix to affected users via Windows Update.